# correct way to send strings with java socket using java NIO

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, nio

The situation is this I have a server that listens for connections and uses a selector, a client connects and sends a string, the server receives it and sends another string to the client, after which the client ends.

The server correctly receives the string sent by the client and sends its string but at this point the client enters an infinite loop, executes the read() but it is as if it could not take the data from the buffer, in fact the string is always empty, how could I do?

Server code

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);                         
buf.rewind();
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
while(client.read(buf)>0) {                         
    buf.flip();
    while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
        tmp.append((char) buf.get());
    }
    buf.clear();
}
System.out.println("String received " + tmp.getBytes());                    
String string = "hello"

buf.rewind();
buf.put(string.getBytes());
while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
    client.write(buf);
}
buf.clear();
System.out.println("Sending complete.");
```

Client code

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
buf.put(message.getBytes());            
buf.flip();
while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
    socket.write(buf);
}
buf.clear();
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
buf.rewind();
while(socket.read(buf)>0){
    //the client read something cause execute these commands
    buf.flip();
    while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
        //then enter in this infinite loop
        string.append((char) buf.get());
        //It only prints "Read: " no sing of the rest of the string
        System.out.println("Read: " +string.toString());
    }
    buf.clear();                    
}
System.out.println("Client has received: " + string.toString());
```

Comment: You're not calling `ByteBuffer#flip` after `buf.put(string.getBytes());`.

Comment: you're right I simply forgot it thanks

Comment: To be more accurate, you're not calling it before writing. You need to flip before get or write, and clear or compact afterwards. @JacobG.